# Can't understand the two returns from a function

Tags: go

I know Go can return multiple values from a single function/method, but I can't understand WHERE are the values returning from.

```
ok, err := DB.SelectWithWhere(d, goqu.Ex{
    "location": id,
}).Limit(1).ScanStruct(d)
```

`SelectWithWhere` only returns one value.

```
func (s *SqlDB) SelectWithWhere(m models.Model, e goqu.Expression, args ...interface{}) *goqu.SelectDataset {
    ds := s.goqu.From(m.Table()).Where(e)
    if len(args) > 0 {
        ds = ds.Select(args...)
    }
    return ds //Single Return
}
```

It's returning false to `ok` and it's wrong, because it is finding a result from database, the values are stored in `d`  structure.

Anyone could tell me why is `ok` returning as false and WHERE is the second return value comming from?

I Found:

> ScanStruct
>
> Scans a row into a slice a struct, returns false if a row wasnt found

Is it possible to return 1 value from the `SelectWithWhere` function and the other one from `ScanStruct`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 3):

`SelectWithWhere` returns one value, which is then used as a receiver for `Limit(1)`. That returns one value, which is used as a receiver for `ScanStruct`, which returns two values. Your code can be rewritten as:

```
x:=DB.SelectWithWhere(d, goqu.Ex{"location": id})
y:=x.Limit(1)
ok, err:=y.ScanStruct(d)
```

Comment: Thanks. So the both values returned by `ScanStruct` are a `flag` and an error message?

Comment: Yes, ScanStruct is what's returning those two values